# Comparing OLS regression coefficients with SUR in SAS

Tags: regression, stata, sas, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I have the following code in Stata that I'm looking for the equivalent in SAS.

Stata code:

```
regress DV X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 if groupID == 0
est tab, b se stats(r2_a)
est store groupID0

regress DV X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 if groupID == 1
est tab, b se stats(r2_a)
est store groupID1

suest groupID0 groupID2, vce(cluster firmID)
test [groupID0_mean]_cons = [groupID1_mean]_cons
test [groupID0_mean]X1 = [groupID1_mean]X1
test [groupID0_mean]X2 = [groupID1_mean]X2
test [groupID0_mean]X3 = [groupID1_mean]X3
test [groupID0_mean]X4 = [groupID1_mean]X4
test [groupID0_mean]X5 = [groupID1_mean]X5
```

The first two `regress` statements perform OLS and save the coefficients, which I know how to do in SAS.  The `suest` statements performs seeming unrelated regression on both group1 and group2 with clustered standard errors and then tests the equality of coefficients.  It's the block of code from `suest` down that I cannot figure out in SAS. 
  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the SUEST statements will end up being LSMEANS statement but it does depend on what PROC you're using, REG or GLM?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the SUR option in the PROC SYSLIN statement specifies seemingly unrelated regression, as shown in the following statements:

```
proc syslin data=in sur;
 demand: model q = r y s;
 supply: model q = r u;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's the subsequent testing for equality between coefficients from two SUR regressions that I can't seem to figure out.